# How to copy file from isolated storage to skydrive

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, onedrive, live-sdk

I need to backup data from my WP7 app to Skydrive, this file is xml file. I know how to connect to skydrive and how to create folder on skydrive:

```
try
{
    var folderData = new Dictionary<string, object>();
    folderData.Add("name", "Smart GTD Data");

    LiveConnectClient liveClient = new LiveConnectClient(mySession);
    liveClient.PostAsync("me/skydrive", folderData);
}
catch (LiveConnectException exception)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Error creating folder: " + exception.Message);
}
```

but I don't know how to copy file from isolated storage to skydrive.

How can I do it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's easy, you can use the [`liveClient.UploadAsync`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/live/microsoft.live.liveconnectclient.uploadasync) method

```
private void uploadFile(LiveConnectClient liveClient, Stream stream, string folderId, string fileName) {
    liveClient.UploadCompleted += onLiveClientUploadCompleted;
    liveClient.UploadAsync(folderId, fileName, stream, OverwriteOption.Overwrite);
}

private void onLiveClientUploadCompleted(object sender, LiveOperationCompletedEventArgs args) {
    ((LiveConnectClient)sender).UploadCompleted -= onLiveClientUploadCompleted;
    // notify someone perhaps
    // todo: dispose stream
}
```

You can get a stream from IsolatedStorage and send it like this

```
public void sendFile(LiveConnectClient liveClient, string fileName, string folderID) {
    using (IsolatedStorageFile storage = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication()) {
        Stream stream = storage.OpenFile(filepath, FileMode.Open);
        uploadFile(liveClient, stream, folderID, fileName);
    }
}
```

Note that you need to use the *folder ID* when uploading the stream. Since you are creating the folder, you can get this ID when the creation of the folder is complete. Simply register for the `PostCompleted` event when posting the request for folderData.

Here's an example

```
private bool hasCheckedExistingFolder = false;
private string storedFolderID;

public void CreateFolder() {
    LiveConnectClient liveClient = new LiveConnectClient(session);
    // note that you should send a "liveClient.GetAsync("me/skydrive/files");" 
    // request to fetch the id of the folder if it already exists
    if (hasCheckedExistingFolder) {
      sendFile(liveClient, fileName, storedFolderID);
      return;
    }
    Dictionary<string, object> folderData = new Dictionary<string, object>();
    folderData.Add("name", "Smart GTD Data");
    liveClient.PostCompleted += onCreateFolderCompleted;
    liveClient.PostAsync("me/skydrive", folderData);
}

private void onCreateFolderCompleted(object sender, LiveOperationCompletedEventArgs e) {
    if (e.Result == null) {
        if (e.Error != null) {
          onError(e.Error);
        }
        return;
    }
    hasCheckedExistingFolder = true;
    // this is the ID of the created folder
    storedFolderID = (string)e.Result["id"];
    LiveConnectClient liveClient = (LiveConnectClient)sender;
    sendFile(liveClient, fileName, storedFolderID);
}
```

Comment: Great it works, but I have problem in specify path to skydrive if I use my/skydrive then everything works great but I have folder MyData on skydrive and this is place where I want to upload that file but if I use path my/skydrive/MyData then app crash. How can I specify path correct?

Comment: That's a good question, I forgot to mention it. It's not the folder name, it's the folder *id*. You have to fetch the folder information and extract the id from the result, and use that id when uploading.

Comment: thak you, can I get folder Id when I create folder (as in code to create folder what I wrote in my fisrst post)?

Comment: @Earlgray: I updated my answer with an example. The answer is yes.

Comment: there is another problem when I write to PostComplete event: string storedFolderId = (string)e.Result["data"];
MessageBox.Show(storedFolderId); then app crash..

Comment: What exception do you get?

Comment: it show exception on row string storedFolderId = (string)e.Result["data"]; - KeyNotFoundException was not unhandled

Comment: Hm, what keys are available? You can check that when debugging.

Comment: Im not shure where is it so this is print screen of debug: http://img708.imageshack.us/img708/3897/scrtb.png

Comment: Check the keys in the entries property

Comment: Ive got it correct version is e.Result["id"]. Thank you very much. Next I have last question ho can I override folder if folder with same name exist?

Comment: Oops, sorry about that. Why would you want to override a folder? Do you mean remove all files in the folder and then recreate it? I don't think your users would like that..

Comment: because there is problem in create folder code when folder with same name exist. I need to create (or get folder) and then overide its content winth new data

Comment: @Earlgray: That's why you need to call `liveClient.GetAsync("me/skydrive/files");`, as noted in the code comment, and extract the id from the folder with the same name.